# How can I configure my Synology NAS's wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, nas, wireless-access-point, synology

When I want to configure my **Synology DS213air**'s Wireless network, I get to see the following options:

[image]

When I choose Wireless AP and click <kbd>Apply</kbd> I expect to get a list of the networks I can connect to so I can choose mine. But nothing happens.
Nevertheless the user manual says:

> *Join a wireless network:* The wizard will scan available wireless access points or Ad-Hoc networks with their signal strength and security status. If the access point you want to access is locked with password protection, the wizard will ask you to enter the password.

My network is WPA2-PSK protected, but my password isn't asked for. Worse: my NAS is listed as an unprotected wireless network.

How can I make my NAS an AP of my network, so that it shares the same level of protection?

Comment: Setting up an AP should not involve joining an existing network. just set up the AP as though it were a new network, using the same SSID, security settings, and password. Join Wireless network is a completely differant option that creating an AP. Since you created a new wireless network by creating a new AP, you now need to configure it, which is why it appears to be unprotected now. So, what are you trying to do? create an AP so other devices can connect to your NAS for wireless service, or do you want the NAS to connect to an existing wireless netword as a client?

Comment: @Frank thanks for your comment.  I want to access the NAS from different devices through my current protected wireless network. Internet connection isn't necessary, protection is. I'm not sure, it looks like both options would be OK, right? Neither options gives me anything about SSID or password settings.

Comment: Then you want to remove the AP settings you added, and just use the Join Wireless Network option. you want to config the NAS as a wifi client, so it connects to the network through the wifi.